How to systematically find the kernel of a channel from its Kraus operators?
A quantum channel is a completely positive trace-preserving map. Given a quantum state $\rho$ and channel $N$, let the output be $N(\rho)$.
Given the Kraus operators of the channel, how can one find its kernel?

To take an explicit example, let $N: A\rightarrow B$ be a projection from a 2-qubit space to a 1-qubit space such as a channel with Kraus operators $\{\vert 0\rangle\langle 00\vert, \vert 0\rangle\langle 11\vert, \vert 1\rangle\langle 01\vert, \vert 1\rangle\langle 10\vert \}$.
We obviously lost the ability to tell $\vert 00\rangle$ apart from $\vert 11\rangle$ so it is easy to say by inspection that $\vert 00\rangle\langle 00\vert - \vert 11\rangle\langle 11\vert$ is in its kernel. How can one do this systematically for an arbitrary channel only from its Kraus operators $\{K_i\}$?
Note: Question edited after comment by gIS.

a quantum map/channel is a linear function, so yes you can talk about its kernel and image the same way you do for any linear operator. Your example shows that $|\psi\rangle!\langle \psi|-I/4$ is in the ker of $N$, compatibly with the fact that the ker of a trace-preserving operation can only contain traceless operators, as you pointed out. You could just use a standard depolarising qubit channel to make a similar argument btw. And in general, yes, the ker of a linear operator is associated to its non-injectivity (dim ker = number of identified independent ops). Is that what you're asking?

@gIS I see. I think your comment cleared some confusions for me. I will edit the question to a more clear question. Thanks!

I'd be surprised if you can say anything meaningful directly from the Kraus operators. Kraus rank one channels -- unitaries -- are invertible and so is a partially depolarizing channel with full Kraus rank. I think in general the best thing you can do is to convert the Kraus operators into a matrix representation and then perform Gaussian elimination.

Let me add that for Pauli channels, you can find the kernel by performing a Fourier transform on the convex coefficients (= squared 2-norm of the Kraus operators).

This post may be considered a duplicate of this question which is why I'd also like to link to my contribution to said post
